# How to filter exact data in adapter class

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-filterable

I am searching data that is coming from service through Edit Text but the searching is not done properly on every search its filter wrong data and some time list data is added more than one time in my layout can any one help me please.

Filter Class

```
private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
        ArrayList<CountriesModel> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<CountriesModel>();

        if (mOriginalValues == null) {
            mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<CountriesModel>(ArrayListModel); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
        }


        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

            // set the Original result to return
            results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
            results.values = mOriginalValues;
        } else {
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getCountry_name();
                if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                    FilteredArrList.add(new CountriesModel());
                }
            }
            // set the Filtered result to return
            results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
            results.values = FilteredArrList;
        }
        return results;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        ArrayListModel = (ArrayList<CountriesModel>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

}

Fragment:

```
        EditTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                Log.e( "Databe  ", s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // String txt=  EditTextSearch.getText().toString();
                Log.e( "Dataon  ", s.toString());
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                       /*String txt=  EditTextSearch.getText().toString();
                  */
                Log.e( "Dataaf  ", s.toString());
                  /*  String text = EditTextSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(text);*/
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That's a *very* long code sample - can you trim it down into a [mcve]?

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<CountriesModel> { ...` and override its `onBind` and `matches` methods

Comment: no sir  its doen't work @pskink

Comment: so what is your implementation of `matches` method?

Comment: sir in my case list show its top data in any search means list is not updated properly

Comment: so what is your implementation of `matches` method?

Comment: what you have mean from matches method??

Comment: see my **first** comment above ("you need some custom ...")

Comment: sir it will done thanks for help